# Error in intellij Idea

Tags: intellij-idea

I have an eclipse background. Something that i noticed recently is that it is not easy to spot files that contains error in the navigator view of Intellij (scala). In eclipse those file are highlighted in red.

Is there something similar, a configuration similar that can tell you when there is problems? (without having to open windows on your own)

Many thanks,

-M-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

unlike eclipse, intellij does not compile the whole project all of the time, so it cannot maintain a list of "issues" as eclipse does.

you can either build your project (build --> rebuild project) in which case it'll fail and list the errors, or run inspections on the entire project (analyze --> inspect code) which will find warnings on top of errors.

Comment: You can enable option to compile class when changed in settings menu since idea 13.x